# Android drawText missing characters on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawtext

I had an android app that displays a scale and it worked fine on all version until 5.0 (Lollipop)  where the all the texts drawn with drawText method are somehow truncated.
Only the second letter of a tow letters text is displayed.
i.e. The first mark is only '0' letter but is not displayed.
For the second 2 marks (40, and 80) only 0 is displayed and for the rest, 140... 250, no text is displayed.
The text size seems to be OK but not all the chars are displayed.
The image is scaled in [0..1, 0..1] square.
I have found and try lot of posts on drawText but none of them helped.
(View.setLayerType() all combinations, setLinearText(true), Paint.Style.FILL...)

```
private void drawScale(final Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    // On canvas, North is 0 degrees, East is 90 degrees, South is 180 etc.
    // We start the scale somewhere South-West so we need to first rotate the canvas.
    canvas.rotate(mScaleRotation, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    final int totalTicks = mDivisions * mSubdivisions + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalTicks; i++) {
        final float y1 = mScaleRect.top;
        final float y2 = y1 + 0.015f; // height of division
        final float y3 = y1 + 0.045f; // height of subdivision

        final float value = getValueForTick(i);
        final Paint paint = getRangePaint(value);
        if (0 == value % mDivisions) {
            // Draw a division tick
            canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y3, paint);
            // Draw the text 0.15 away from the division tick
            canvas.drawText(valueString(value), 0.5f, y3 + 0.045f, paint);
        }
        else {
            // Draw a subdivision tick
            canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, paint);
        }
        canvas.rotate(mSubdivisionAngle, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}
```

where a range paint is create like this

```
mRangePaints[i] = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mRangePaints[i].setColor(mRangeColors[i]);
mRangePaints[i].setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mRangePaints[i].setStrokeWidth(0.005f);
mRangePaints[i].setTextSize(0.05f);
mRangePaints[i].setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
mRangePaints[i].setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
mRangePaints[i].setShadowLayer(0.005f, 0.002f, 0.002f, mTextShadowColor);
```

and canvas is created like this

```
mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBackground);
```

This is a capture from and android 5.0

[Android 5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvrKg.png)

This is capture from an android 4.4

[Android <5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRjRO.png)

Any help, clue, etc... will be deeply appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Thank you for suggestions,

I have wrote a function that re-scale all the sizes as for an textSize 10f.
Every original call to canvas.drawText was replaced with a call to this

drawScaledText(canvas, ... original values ...)

Everything seem to work fine.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void drawScaledText(Canvas canvas, String text, float x, float y, Paint paint, float scale) {
    float originalStrokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
    float originalTextSize = paint.getTextSize();
    float textScaling = 10f/originalTextSize;
    paint.setStrokeWidth(originalStrokeWidth * textScaling);
    paint.setTextSize(originalTextSize * textScaling);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scale/textScaling, scale/textScaling);
    canvas.drawText(text, x * textScaling, y * textScaling, paint);
    canvas.restore();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(originalStrokeWidth);
    paint.setTextSize(originalTextSize);
}
```

Comment: what was your scale param? i use every number and non of them working :( i use this library and have this problem

Comment: @AmirHosseinGhasemi Did you ever figure this out? I am also using this library and cannot seem to find a good answer on how to fix this. OP's solution does not seem to work for me either.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me but only with textSize bigger  than 1f. AS Kuffs said, the drawText function doesn't work well if size is under 1f. All my drawings are done in a 1f x 1f rectangle so that the image could be easily scales to any dimension. That was the reason for which my text size was originally 0.05f. The function I wrote, draw a text with a bigger size but then rescale the whole canvas to match the entire image.

Comment: @Luci I have the same "configuration", a 1f x 1f rectangle and a wanted textSize of 0.05f. But I can't figure the good parameters to use with your function to draw my text where I want.
I want my text to be drawn at x = 0.5f, y = 0.8f with 0.05f size. What values should I use for Paint.textSize and the scale parameter ?

Comment: @Magnas here are my settings for default text paint  getDefaultTextValuePaint() {
  final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  paint.setColor(mTextValueColor);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(0.005f);
  paint.setTextSize(mTextValueSize);
  paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
  paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
  paint.setShadowLayer(0.01f, 0.002f, 0.002f, mTextShadowColor);
  return paint;
 }  where TextValueSize is 0.3f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canvas.DrawText()` and `canvas.DrawTextOnPath()` do not work well at sizes under 1

Increase your font size. You can scale your canvas to compensate.

See answer to this question.
[Android 4.2.1 wrong character kerning (spacing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974129/android-4-2-1-wrong-character-kerning-spacing)